# Flutter design wave quadraticBezierTo

Tags: flutter

in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56917369/1830228) we have solved design wave `quadraticBezierTo`, but that's half of wave quadraticBezierTo and i want to have full design like with this screen shot:

[image]

and now my question is how can we change this below code to have another half design on right side of that

## this below class make this

[image]

```
class WaveClipperTwo extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  bool reverse;

  WaveClipperTwo({this.reverse = false});

  final int _coefficient = 16;
  double get _minStep => 1 / _coefficient;
  double get _preCenter => _minStep * (_coefficient / 2 - 1);
  double get _postCenter => _minStep * (_coefficient / 2 + 1);
  double get _preEnd => _minStep * (_coefficient - 2);

  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    var path = Path();
    path.moveTo(0.0, 0.0);
    if(!reverse) {
      path.lineTo(0.0, size.height - 20.0);
      path.lineTo(size.width * _preCenter, size.height - 20.0);
      path.cubicTo(size.width/2, size.height - 20.0, size.width/2, size.height - 40.0, size.width * _postCenter, size.height - 40.0);
      path.lineTo(size.width * _preEnd, size.height - 40.0);
      path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width, size.height - 40.0, size.width, size.height - 20.0);
      path.lineTo(size.width, 0.0);
      path.close();
    }else{
      path.lineTo(0.0, 20);
      path.lineTo(size.width * _preCenter, 20.0);
      path.cubicTo(size.width/2, 20.0, size.width/2, 40.0, size.width * _postCenter, 40.0);
      path.lineTo(size.width * _preEnd, 40.0);
      path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width, 40, size.width, 20.0);
      path.lineTo(size.width, 0.0);
      path.close();
    }

    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => false;
}
```

Comment: @Andrey Turkovsky could you help me on this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you are:

[image]

Change innerWidth constant when you want to make middle part wider or narrower.

```
class TopFeedsWaveCurve extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  final double innerWidth = 100;
  final double innerHeight = 20; 
  final double topOffcet = 60;

  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    var halfW = innerWidth / 2;
    var height = innerHeight + topOffcet;
    var path = Path()
      ..moveTo(0.0, 0.0)
      ..lineTo(0.0, topOffcet)
      ..lineTo(size.width / 2 - halfW - innerHeight, topOffcet)
      ..cubicTo(
        size.width / 2 - halfW,
        topOffcet,
        size.width / 2 - halfW,
        height,
        size.width / 2 - halfW + innerHeight,
        height,
      )
      ..lineTo(size.width / 2 + halfW - innerHeight, height)
      ..cubicTo(
        size.width / 2 + halfW,
        height,
        size.width / 2 + halfW,
        topOffcet,
        size.width / 2 + halfW + innerHeight,
        topOffcet,
      )
      ..lineTo(size.width, topOffcet)
      ..lineTo(size.width, 0);

    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => true;
}
```

Comment: could you help me how can i change top horizontal bar height?

Comment: I've add extra variables play with them, hope it will help to make your design happens.